# BERT with train, dev, test, predicion mode

Tags: classification, bert-language-model

I am doing a text classification task with BERT. I am basically using [run_classifier.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_classifier.py).
This code uses train.tsv and dev.tsv (with labels) to fine-tune BERT and a test.tsv (without labels) to make predictions. However, I need to use train-dev-test splits to train the model (train set), calculate the hyperparameters and loss function (dev set), and evaluate the performance (test set). As regular train-dev-test splits all include labels. 
I also have a forth unlabeled dataset to make the prediction on. Do you know of any repository that implements BERT with 4 modes (train-dev-test-prediction)?

Answer (score 0):

We can define a method that takes path to different datasets and returns the transformed datasets that could be used training, testing and validation purposes. The key is the `transformation` method.

Below is a snippet that generates test and training for IMDB sentiment analysis (uses `keras-bert`). Note the `load_data` which does the transformation.

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname="aclImdb.tar.gz", 
    origin="http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz", 
    extract=True,
)

token_dict = {}
with codecs.open(vocab_path, 'r', 'utf8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        token = line.strip()
        token_dict[token] = len(token_dict)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(token_dict)

def load_data(path, tagset):
    global tokenizer
    indices, sentiments = [], []
    for folder, sentiment in tagset:
        folder = os.path.join(path, folder)
        for name in tqdm(os.listdir(folder)):
            with open(os.path.join(folder, name), 'r') as reader:
                  text = reader.read()
            ids, segments = tokenizer.encode(text, max_len=SEQ_LEN)
            indices.append(ids)
            sentiments.append(sentiment)
  
    items = list(zip(indices, sentiments))
    np.random.shuffle(items)
    indices, sentiments = zip(*items)
    indices = np.array(indices)
    mod = indices.shape[0] % BATCH_SIZE
    if mod > 0:
        indices, sentiments = indices[:-mod], sentiments[:-mod]
    return [indices, np.zeros_like(indices)], np.array(sentiments)
  
train_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), 'aclImdb', 'train')
test_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), 'aclImdb', 'test')

tagset = [('neg', 0), ('pos', 1)]
id_to_labels = {0: 'negative', 1: 'positive'}
train_x, train_y = load_data(train_path, tagset)
test_x, test_y = load_data(test_path, tagset)
```

For details on input and output and complete implementation (and text classification in general using BERT fine tuning) Refer: **[Text Classification Using BERT Fine Tuning: Understandinginput to keras-bert](https://pysnacks.com/machine-learning/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/#understanding-the-input-to-keras-bert)** . It has working Google Colab GPU implementation for binary, mutli-class, and multi-label text classification for 20 Newsgroup, IMDB sentiment Analysis and Toxic comment classification and uses separate training and test sets.